# Problems with for loop and vectors to create a new data file with 64 separate txt files

Tags: r, loops

```
dat08 <- c() for(i in 0:63) {
  temp <- read.table(paste0("run",i,".txt"), sep=" ") dat08 <- rbind(dat08, temp)

}
```

This is what I have currently, but I am not sure how to go about fixing these errors:

1. Error: unexpected 'for' in "dat08 <- c() for"
2. Error: unexpected symbol in "  temp <- read.table(paste0("run",i,".txt"), sep=" ") dat08"
3. Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: It looks like your errors were not having the proper line breaks in the code.  Either have a return after each line of code or a semicolon.

Comment: @Dave2e I’ve rolled back your changes since they invalidated the question.